# Is the ordered of df.corr() columns ensured

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, correlation

In Pandas we can generate a correlation matrix with [`.corr()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html). My question is quite simple: is the column order of the original dataframe preserved? From my testing it seems the case, but I want to be sure.

I am asking because I am on Python 3.7.3 where dictionaries maintain insertion order. I don't know if the current question is related to that, but if Pandas uses dictionaries behind the scenes, then it might very well be that `corr()` is ordered as expected in Python 3.6+ but not in lower versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you look at the [source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/f6a5dd4b8c450d73f3bec964b05cca32cef4bb71/pandas/core/frame.py#L7432) for `corr`, the following code is at the start:

```py
numeric_df = self._get_numeric_data()
        cols = numeric_df.columns
        idx = cols.copy()
        mat = numeric_df.values
```

As you see here, as long as the method `_get_numeric_data` preserves order, `corr` should preserve order as well.  Diving a bit deeper into `_get_numeric_data`, you can see [this block](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/f6a5dd4b8c450d73f3bec964b05cca32cef4bb71/pandas/core/internals/managers.py#L706):

```py
self._consolidate_inplace()
return self.combine([b for b in self.blocks if b.is_numeric], copy)
```

`_consolidate_inplace` constructs consolidated sections of the dataframe in a tuple (order preserved), while `_get_numeric_data` uses a list comprehension to filter this tuple to only numeric blocks (order still preserved).

More to the point, `pandas` isn't actually using a dictionary for your column names. 
 `columns` themselves are [just instances](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/f6a5dd4b8c450d73f3bec964b05cca32cef4bb71/pandas/core/indexes/base.py#L166) of the `Index` class, which (from the doc string) is ordered.

So, to answer your question: yes, order is guaranteed in `corr`, because the way it obtains and iterates through the dataframe columns also preserves order.